# WARNING: "spi_register_driver" undefined

Tags: kernel, kernel-module

I am about to write my first kernel module. However I get a strange warning, when I am about to build the module:

```
"WARNING: "spi_register_driver" undefined"
```

This warning is ending with a failing insmod, if I dare to load the module. I noticed, that I get these warning also with other spi interface functions I want to use (like spi_sync). I don't know why these errors happen, because the header files look OK.

Makefile:

```
obj-m += MS5611.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Init function:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/mod_devicetable.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/spi/spi.h>
#include <linux/of.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/kfifo.h>
#include <linux/mutex.h>

// My Init function
int MS5611_init(void) {
  int iRet;
  int iDevID;

  printk(KERN_ALERT "Init MS5611: Creating device file.\n");

  INIT_KFIFO(_MS5611_REPORTS);
  iRet = spi_register_driver(&_MS5611_DRIVER);
  // ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

spi_register_driver is an GPL symbol. You need to license your module as GPL or you can't access these symbols. To do this use MODULE_LICENSE("GPL"). At last, that what was happening with me...

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your kernel was not compiled with SPI support. Or, you didn't load the SPI module

Comment: I tried to rebuild it with SPI support. At least I thought so, maybe something went wrong.

Comment: ls /sys/bus/` if you can see `spi`, then you should have the SPI subsystem